# PageNumber-Fillter for Finder in .Net Assembly Connector

Tags: bcs, filter, external-content-type, external-list

I'm currently trying to use an *PageNumber-Filter* for an Finder-Method in an .NET Assembly Connector. The relevant Part of the Method-Definition of the *ReadList*-Method looks the following.

```
<Method Name="ReadList" IsStatic="false">
 <FilterDescriptors>
<FilterDescriptor Type="PageNumber" FilterField="ID" Name="PageNumberFilter">
  <Properties>
    <Property Name="UsedForDisambiguation" Type="System.Boolean">false</Property>
    <Property Name="IsDefault" Type="System.Boolean">true</Property>
    <Property Name="CaseSensitive" Type="System.Boolean">false</Property>
    <Property Name="PageSize" Type="System.Int32">50</Property>
    <Property Name="SortType" Type="System.Boolean">true</Property>
  </Properties>
</FilterDescriptor>
</FilterDescriptors>
<Parameters>
   <Parameter Direction="In" Name="@ID">
       <TypeDescriptor TypeName="System.Int32" Name="ID" AssociatedFilter="PageNumberFilter" />
   </Parameter>
  <Parameter Direction="Return" Name="returnParameter">
       <TypeDescriptor ... />
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>
...
</Method
```

But in the ULS-Trace I found the following message after unsuccessfully trying to create a list from the External Content Type:

```
VLPROV: Finder 'ReadList' has a filter of type 'PageNumber'. These filters are not supported for external lists.Creating no view for this finder.
```

So the questions are:

- Is the *PageNumber-Filter* supported for .NET Assembly Connectors Finder-Methods?
- If yes, what is wrong with my approach.
- If it is not supported, what is the best approach to realize paging in an .NET Assembly Connector Finder-Method. I'm aware of the solution other questions/answers are proposing. e.g [Sharepoint 2010 external list paging – server side in the lightning tools blog](http://www.lightningtools.com/blog/archive/2010/06/25/sharepoint-2010-external-list-paging-ndash-server-side.aspx). But I don't have sequential, numerical IDs provided by the external system.

Best regards and Happy new Year

Joachim